# Unable to implement sample d3.js flle

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I tried to modify from this sample .
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346395

I build a `index.html` and `data.tsv` with those codes inside .

Then ,I change `<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>` to `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`

As a result , no charts are shown on `index.html`

Whats wrong with it?

I put `index.html` and `data.tsv` in same directory

## the code I have made changes

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>....
```

to

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>.....
```

Result:

Console :
[image]

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) to see what has changed from version 3 to version 4.

Comment: @jrook Now ,I m trying to use `https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js`. But it is still not working

Comment: Please share your code and indicate the changes you have made to the example.

Comment: @jrook I changes I line only in `index.html`

Comment: Are you loading a http:// src within a https:// page?

Comment: @webbm I tried both http and https .Both are not working

Comment: What console error messages do you see?

Comment: @webbm no console error .I just use notepad to edit both file

Comment: I highly suspect it's related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local when you open the index.html file in your browser, and look at the console output, is there nothing there?

Comment: @webbm  When I go to the console , anything I should type to check the error

Comment: @evalwt so what's the error message?

Comment: may be you need to change the url of d3 ajax call to http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/1346395/data.tsv

Comment: @ArslArsl  But I should make a local .tsv for my personal data

Comment: @webbm I post the console here. I think nothing there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is - you need a local server to test it with your local data. d3.tsv() - makes ajax call so it needs a server.

Comment: yes , I didn't host on my localhost. I just treat as simple html and js. Can I use xmapp to perform it ? Or any simple methods which don't require local server

Comment: Anything that can return you that file after a request - is actually a server. I believe you can go with xampp as well.

Comment: may I change tsv file to dom file ,so that I no need to run server?

Comment: what do you mean `dom file`?  You will need a server anyway. Remote or local. It's up to you. It will not work over `file://`

Comment: I try running a local server .I put the index.html along with data.tsv .That is still not working .

Comment: how do you require the file? url please

Comment: I just put two file index.html & data.tsv under the htdoc .And I make change to `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>` in `index.html` .What url you refer to ?my server?

Comment: what url you put in parenthesis in tsv()

Comment: `d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {` Just follow the sample code

Comment: Should be my typo. Thanks anyway .One more last question .There are two items and subpages :apple & oranges  in the sample .What place should I make changes in codes if I want to add new items

Comment: for the `data.tsv`, can I just add a new column with the notepad

Comment: Yes you can add new entries right in to data.tsv - and if no mistakes - the visualization will change accordingly. Yes you can use notepad app.